# Can a ConcurrentHashMap be externally synchronized in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am using a ConcurrentHashMap, and I need to iterate over all its elements when calculating a new element that is not present yet and do some other modifications possibly over the same map.

I wanted those operations be atomic, and block the ConcurrentHashMap to prevent from getting an exception derived from concurrency.

The solution I programmed was to synchronize the ConcurrentHashMap object with itself as lock, but Sonar reports a major issue, so I do not know whether that solution is correct

Proposed code:

Modification to the original text

```
public class MyClass<K, V> {
    ConcurrentHashMap<K, V> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public V get(K key) {
        return map.computeIfAbsent(key, this::calculateNewElement);
    }

    protected V calculateNewElement(K key) {
        V result;
        // the following line throws the sonar issue:
        synchronized(map) {
            // calculation of the new element (assignating it to result)
            // with iterations over the whole map
            // and possibly with other modifications over the same map
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This code triggers a Sonar major issue:

> Multi-threading - Synchronization performed on util.concurrent
> instance
>
> findbugs:JLM_JSR166_UTILCONCURRENT_MONITORENTER
>
> This method performs synchronization on an object that is an instance
> of a class from the java.util.concurrent package (or its subclasses).
> Instances of these classes have their own concurrency control
> mechanisms that are orthogonal to the synchronization provided by the
> Java keyword synchronized. For example, synchronizing on an
> AtomicBoolean will not prevent other threads from modifying the
> AtomicBoolean.
>
> Such code may be correct, but should be carefully reviewed and
> documented, and may confuse people who have to maintain the code at a
> later date.

Comment: Because you are passing the `ConcurrentHashMap` around, you are exposing yourself to having other threads performing operations on it without synchronizing. You should consider wrapping the `ConcurrentHashMap` so that all operations are synchronised. There may be no need to use a `ConcurrentHashMap` at all.

Comment: »Such code may be correct, but should be carefully reviewed and documented, and may confuse people who have to maintain the code at a later date.« To shut up the analyzer: create a `private (static) final lock = new Object()` and synchronize on that. But the real problem seems to be that you are locking on external variable. You cannot guarantee that other threads will not modify the parameter with a lock. It's probably better to introduce your own type for that which wraps the map and performs necessary synchronization.

Comment: ***Can*** it be synchronized? Yes... ***Should*** it be synchronized? Take a guess...

Comment: Echoing what @tgdavies said, but in slightly different words: `ConcurrentHashMap` has thread-safe methods, but they don't do everything that you need. So, make your _own_ class that _does_ have all of the thread-safe methods that you need. You can hide a `ConcurrentHashMap` (or maybe just a plain `HashMap`) inside your new class as a private member. (@tgdavies: This really should be an "answer.")

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. My code is not relly as I wrote (the map is really an attribute of the class), I will update the text of my question for it be more exact. So I have total control over all the acceses to that ConcurrentHashMap. The thing is that I want to benefit of the Concurency policy of ConcurrentHashMap, that is, blocking only when necessary, and not the whole map, but at the same time being able to iterate over its elements in order to calculate new elements to be put, so I wanted to know if sychronizing with the map as lock, was coordinated with the write lock on that map

Comment: Re, "I wanted to know if sychronizing with the map as lock, was coordinated with the write lock on that map" If [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) does not promise that behavior, (and I'm pretty sure it does not,) then you should not expect that behavior.

Comment: @FranciscoJavierRojas: You cannot have both.  Synchronizing with the map has no connection to the internal concurrency of the ConcurrentHashMap.

Answer (score 5):

If you have to change many nodes for each update, maybe you're using the wrong data structure. Check out concurrent implementations of trees. A persistent collection (that provides immutability plus fast updates) would seem ideal.

There is a method provided for atomic updates:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)

ConcurrentHashMap is built to allow a high degree of concurrent access. (See [this article describing its inner workings](https://dzone.com/articles/how-concurrenthashmap-works-internally-in-java)) If an update is made to an entry using the provided means (such as compute, computeIfPresent, etc.)  that should lock only the segment the entry is in, not the whole thing.

When you lock the whole map for an update you're not getting the benefit of using this specialized data structure. That's what Sonar is complaining about.

There is also the issue that readers have to do locking too, updater threads aren't the only ones that need to lock. This kind of thing is why CHM was invented in the first place.

Comment: Thank you, Nathan, for your answer. I will update text of the question, as it is not accurate enough and does not bound exactly the needs of that synchronization. The thing is that with the synchronization I wanted to prevent from the whole map being modified while the execution is inside that synchronized block. But, as sonar indicated, may be the internal process of that locks the modifications inside the ConcurrentHashMap, has nothing to do with the synchronization lock that I programmed, and in such case the synchronization block would not be effective this way ... And that was my doubt.

Comment: A BiFunction cannot work here, since the insert depends on all entries. It should just be a lock around a regular hash map.

Comment: @Michael: right, compute doesn't work, the question changed.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.amazon.com.tr/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601.

"Concurrent objects do not support 'client side-locking'"

You could perform client side-locking on synchronized collections like.

```
final List<Type> synchronizedList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>()); //do not use another reference to internal array list and access the list using through synchronizedList reference.
```

In this case, you could use;

```
synchronized(synchronizedList){
  //do something with synchronized list.
}
```

NOTE: This might perform badly, namely introduce scability issues because the code is highly serialized. (Amdal's Law).

Concurrent objects are designed for scability. Maybe you can take a snapshot of the map to another 'local' collections and do operations on them. Or you can directly use map without any synchronization. (In this case, some new elements could be added or deleted and your iterator might or might not reflect those changes)

"ConcurrentHashMap, along with the other concurrent collections, further improve on the synchronized collection classes by providing iterators that do not throw ConcurrentModificationException, **thus eliminating the need to lock the collection during iteration.** The iterators returned by ConcurrentHashMap are weakly consistent instead of fail-fast. **A weakly consistent iterator can tolerate concurrent modification, traverses elements as they existed when the iterator was constructed, and may (but is not guaranteed to) reflect modifications to the collection after the construction of the iterator."**

There are operations on ConcurrentHashMap which allows you to perform atomic operations on a specific key like compute, computeIfAbsent, computeIfPresent.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Comment: Very interesting @Ahmet (+1, although I have no time to check that that is correct). My fear was the ConcurrentModificationException. But if it is as you said, may be I would not need synchronization, but with the posibility that a race condition produced a multiple evaluation of calculateNewElement for the same key (on my proposed solution). But in my case that is not crucial.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace your combination of synchronization and access to the map with a "regular" collection and the use of a `ReadWriteLock` (e.g. the `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock`)

See this part of the description of the [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package:

> The "Concurrent" prefix used with some classes in this package is a shorthand indicating several differences from similar "synchronized" classes. For example `java.util.Hashtable` and `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap())` are synchronized. But `ConcurrentHashMap` is "concurrent". A concurrent collection is thread-safe, but not governed by a single exclusion lock. In the particular case of ConcurrentHashMap, it safely permits any number of concurrent reads as well as a large number of concurrent writes. "Synchronized" classes can be useful when you need to prevent all access to a collection via a single lock, at the expense of poorer scalability. In other cases in which multiple threads are expected to access a common collection, "concurrent" versions are normally preferable. And unsynchronized collections are preferable when either collections are unshared, or are accessible only when holding other locks.

From the docs of [`ReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html):

> A `ReadWriteLock` maintains a pair of associated locks, one for read-only operations and one for writing. The read lock may be held simultaneously by multiple reader threads, so long as there are no writers. The write lock is exclusive.

The "reentrant" implementation mimicks the behaviour of a `synchronized` block:
(from the docs of [`ReentrantLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html))

> A reentrant mutual exclusion Lock with the same basic behavior and semantics as the implicit monitor lock accessed using synchronized methods and statements, but with extended capabilities.

Your code for it could look like this:

```java
public class MyClass<K, V> {
    private final Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
    private final ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private final Lock readLock = lock.readLock();
    private final Lock writeLock = lock.writeLock();

    public V get(K key) {
        readLock.lock();
        try {
            return map.computeIfAbsent(key, this::calculateNewElement);
        } finally {
            readLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    protected V calculateNewElement(K key) {
        readLock.unlock();
        writeLock.lock();
        try {
            V result;
            // calculation of the new element (assigning it to result)
            // with iterations over the whole map
            // and possibly with other modifications over the same map
            return result;
        } finally {
            writeLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public V put(K key, V value) {
        writeLock.lock();
        try {
            return map.put(key, value);
        } finally {
            writeLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

With this implementation reads are blocked while a write is happening and vice versa. Multiple reads are still possible at the same time, but write is exclusive.

But you have to take care that the map doesn't "escape" the object and is accessed somehow differently - also inside the class you have to protect all the access to the map with the lock.

The JavaDocs of [`ReentrantReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) provides you with examples and some conditions you should be aware of (e.g. a size limit of locks).

Comment: thank you, cyber for your answer.
It seems preferable to synchronization (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all answers, I could finally program a solution.

```
public class MyClass<K, V> {
    ConcurrentHashMap<K, V> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public V get(K key) {
        V result = map.get(key);
        if(result == null) {
            result = calculateNewElement(key);
        }
        return 
    }

    public synchronized void put(K key, V value) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    protected synchronized V calculateNewElement(K key) {
        V result = map.get(key);
        if(result == null) {
            // calculation of the new element (assignating it to result)
            // with iterations over the whole map
            // and possibly with other modifications over the same map

            put(key, result);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I will describe the problem a little more:

**Description of the particular problem that the solucion tries to solve:**

- K has two attributes which are objects of Class<?> type (let's call them originClass and destinationClass),
- and V is a translator from a Pojo with a **originClass** ( or one of its superclasses) to a Pojo with **destinationClass** (or one of its derived classes), so it fits the translation originClass -> destinationClass

and when V is not found for a particular K, then

calculateNewElement function tries to look for a non direct path between an originClass and destinationClass,

(that means that we might have a key (K0) with our originClass and a destinationClass(0)

and another key (K1) that has an origin(1) equals to destinationClass(0), and a destinationClass(1), which is a derived class of our destinationClass).

That could lead to a new V that is a Combination of the Keys:

K0 ( originClass(0) = originClass, destinationClass(0) ) (V0) -->

K1 ( originClass(1) = destinationClass(0), destinationClass(1) (a derived class of destinationClass) ) (V1) -->

K2 ( originClass(2) = destinationClass(1), destinationClass(2) = destinationClass) (direct translation that does not exist in the map)

We could thing of joining K1 and K2 into a new_K, this way:

**put( new_K(originClass(1), destinationClass), V1 )** // this is the new different key put inside calculateNewElement

then the new V (of our original K) created by calculateNewElement would be a combination of K0 and new_K:

V v = new VCombination(K0, new_K), which also will be put by our calculateNewElement function

As in my case put function is called seldom (only during initialization), the synchronization is acceptable.

**This scenario fits with the limitations that Holger metioned below. That in my case do not apply, due to the nature of the particular problem:**

- Only when a "halfway" element did not exactly exist yet then calculateNewElement function will put it in the map
- The new elements (which are a combination of existing ones) only need that the elements of the combination exist in the map, so it is not allowed to remove elements from Map (only clearing it would be acceptable)

Comment: Why do you use `ConcurrentHashMap` ?

Comment: Don't mix `synchronized` keyword with stuff from the `java.utils.concurrent` package. Also set the access of your map to `private`, if you want to prevent "uncontrolled" operations on it.

Comment: There is no need to use your `synchronized` put method inside the already `synchronized` calculateNewElement method. And keep in mind that “possibly with other modifications over the same map” must be restricted to changing mappings of `map`, in other words *must not* include modifications of `V` values already contained in the map.

Comment: @DavidSoroko, I use a ConcurrentHashMap, in order to allow a map.get(xxx), even when another thread execution is inside the synchronized functions (I do not know if it is necessary or if simply with a HashMap it would be enough)

Comment: @cyberbrain , I cannot see why I cannot use another lock (no matters the nature of it) if the functionality I need is not provided by ConcurrentHashMap. Which would be your approach?

Comment: @Holger , I put the "put(key, result)" inside calculateNewElement( xxx ) function, in order that even if a later get on the same key of another thread is invoked while the original thread execution is inside calculateNewElement( xxx ) , the latest get will return the correct value (just set by the original thread).   I have not seen another option to cover this case.

Comment: @Holger I cannot understand the limitations on the modifications done to the ConcurrentHashMap inside calculateNewElement function ...  (may be those limitations would have sense if I used a sentence like:   "map.computeIfAbsent(key, this::calculateNewElement)", as it was in the text of the question (but note that the public V get(K key), has changed its implementation in the proposed solution)). Do you think that the restrictions on modifications over the map still apply in the proposed solution? (I cannot see why)

Comment: May be it is not elegant, but theoretically it could be done, couldn't it?

Comment: Calling the `synchronized` `put`  method from within the `synchronized` `calculateNewElement` method has no effect to other threads at all. But since you’re using a `ConcurrentHashMap` anyway, this doesn’t matter. The `calculateNewElement` method can just call `put` on the map.

Comment: The restriction on modifications of `V` values comes from your intended design; other threads can retrieve values from the map while a thread is still inside `calculateNewElement`. This implies that you must not modify `V` objects that are already in the map or have been in the map, as there might be other threads already (or still) working with these objects and modifying them concurrently is not thread safe. There is no problem with preparing them before putting into the map and you can add, remove, or replace them safely. But after putting them, you must treat them as-if immutable.

Comment: ah, now I see your point. But in my case calculateNewElement function will always produce the same sequence of puts (only if they did not exist in the map when calculateNewElement  was called). And there is a possibility that a race condition (a combination of a calculateNewElement execution and a put execution of another thread) could change the V for a  particular K just added in calculateNewElement. But in my particular case the only important thing is the existence of the Ks iterated during calculateNewElement execution.